# Can't enable CORS for specific API controllers in ASP.NET Core WebApp targeting netcoreapp3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to enable CORS for a specific API controller in an ASP.NET Core application.  First, I install the NuGet package, and this is added to my `.csproj`:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Then, I add the following in my `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

After that, if I add this in my `Configure`, it works:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

However, this enables CORS for all controllers.  I just want to enable it for `SessionApiController`.  If I instead add the `EnableCorsAttribute` to the controller:

```
[Route("api/session")]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
[ApiController]
public class SessionApiController : Controller {
    [...]

    [Route("init")]
    public JsonResult InitSession() {
        [...]
    }
}
```

... it doesn't work, and Chrome gives me a CORS error when I try to access the `/api/session/init` endpoint ("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.").  What am I missing here?

Comment: the CORS has to be activated on API-Side, you could accept all headers but it has to be done on the server side via `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`

Comment: Code LGTM. What happens if you instead decorate the controller method? could you provide a reproduction of your setup?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Decorating the controller method still doesn't add the CORS headers.  I can come up with a minimal reproduction, I guess.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I've setup a minimal reproduction based on the .NET Core WebAPI template available to be cloned from my Github account: https://github.com/jez9999/CorsTest

Comment: @Jota.Toledo If you put the example JS on the webpage of another origin (after including jQuery in the page), it won't work because of CORS policy not kicking in, even though there is a `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` attribute on the controller.  The same applies if the attribute is on the method.  If you then uncomment `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` in the startup instead, it works.

Comment: @Jez your demo project is targeting `netcoreapp3.0`. Is that intentional? are you using the preview sdk in your original project?

Comment: Yes I am using it in the original.

Comment: I was able to solve your issue, Ill add an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the following an ASP.NET Core WebApp:

**App.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Extract from **Startup.cs**:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseCors();  // Doesn't work
        //app.UseCors("AllowAll");  // Works

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Extract from a controller in which you want to apply the `AllowAll` policy:

```
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

In order to correctly apply CORS in it, you need to apply the following changes into the code as described in the [migration MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio):

1. Remove [deprecated `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756), in your case `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`. This results in your `.csproj` looking like:

> ```
>  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
>     <PropertyGroup>
>       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
>     </PropertyGroup>
>   </Project>
> ```

2. Carefully follow the [middleware migration advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure) in the msdocs as **the order is important!**. This results in `Startup#Configure` looking as follows:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
       app.UseRouting();

       // AFAIK in netcoreapp2.2 this was not required
       // to use CORS with attributes.
       // This is now required, as otherwise a runtime exception is thrown
       // UseCors applies a global CORS policy, when no policy name is given
       // the default CORS policy is applied
       app.UseCors(); 

       if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();

       app.UseAuthorization();

       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
           endpoints.MapControllers();
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Yep, solved the problem too.  Basically the 2 issues were: I needed to remove the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` package reference - this is apparently built-in in .NET Core 3.0 - and I needed to move `app.UseCors()` to be *after* `app.UseRouting()` - as you said, order matters.