# Can't enable CORS for specific API controllers in ASP.NET Core WebApp targeting netcoreapp3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-3.1

I have CORS working fine in "normal" {controller}/{action}/{id?} controllers.
However CORS does not work in action methods with specific [Route("routname")] attributes.

Sample controller with route:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> Post([FromBody] Customer value)
{
...
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("payment")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerPaymentResponse>> Pay([FromBody] CustomerPaymentRequest value)
{ 
...
}
```

My ConfigureServices method in startup.cs file looks like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", options => options
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddRouting();           

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

and Configure method looks like this:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
            });
        }
```

If I POST to **/api/customer** CORS is working.

If I POST to **/api/customer/payment** CORS does not work (Chrome says: "... has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.")

I have followed the provided answer for [Can't enable CORS for specific API controllers in ASP.NET Core WebApp targeting netcoreapp3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592654/cant-enable-cors-for-specific-api-controllers-in-asp-net-core-webapp-targeting) but issue still remains for me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could post to /payment. It should work. So your CORS issue is in fact a routing-issue.

Comment: Did you try with EnableCorsAttribute on Controller?

Answer (score 0):

It‘s your RouteAttribute:
With Asp.Net-Framework this could work:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("payment")]

public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerPaymentResponse>> Pay([FromBody] CustomerPaymentRequest value)
    { 
    ...
    }
```

But with Core you need, because with Route, the RouteAttribute of the Controller is overridden:

```
[HttpPost ("payment")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerPaymentResponse>> Pay([FromBody] CustomerPaymentRequest value)
{ 
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikolaus. I tried that but unfortunately, the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I found this post: [Trouble with CORS Policy and .NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317789/trouble-with-cors-policy-and-net-core-3-1)

I had an error inside my Pay method.

As that post says, Sometimes "Non-CORS" .NET Server-side Errors Can Be Returned as CORS Errors